# Images not appearing on site; accessible directly through url

Tags: html, image

I have an HTML site that is using several images that do not load in Chrome [edit: and in some people's Firefoxes, not mine].

Using Chrome inspector I can see that they are given a size of 1px by 1px. Plus, the following inline styling is being added to the jpgs (not the png): `style="display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important; opacity: 0 !important; background-position: 0px 0px;" width="0" height="0"` on my site, though not in the jsfiddle. (Let's focus on the first part.)

When I view the same site locally, they display fine. What the heck? Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/3HtPH/2/.

Edit: thanks to Gaby aka G. Petrioli, I figured out that it's due to AdBlock, which I have installed on Chrome and not my other browsers, blocking any resource named 'ad-_.' AdBlock also blocks a whole lot of class and id names that start with 'ad.'

Comment: There is clearly something else going on, probably some javascript. The behavior you're seeing doesn't have anything to do with the images themselves.

Comment: Look at the fiddle. They're not appearing there, either. Edit: not appearing in chrome.

Comment: yeah, I don't have ad-blocker installed. :)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The non-loading images are named ***ad***-something..

That means you have an ad-blocker (*browser plugin*) that is blocking those images thinking that they are advertisements..

Comment: GENIUS. I did see that drupal was hiding elements that started with 'ad-', but for some reason didn't connect that with the issue with the images.

Comment: Oddly I'm facing a similar problem with adblockplus on firefox and a custom twitter link.

Comment: OMG, thx man! I can't understand what happened with my images!

Comment: Happened for me when using an image style with machine ID `300x250`. Renaming to `300by250` wasn't blocked.

Comment: Just spent 30 mins looking at this thinking it was a Wordpress / plugin problem. Thanks!

Comment: GENIUS indeed, Thanks for preventing myself from going mad :)

Answer (score 0):

The host uses [hotlink prevention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_linking#Prevention), i.e. they're blocking the usage of their images from outside their own domain.

Comment: Thanks, but they're not. The jsfiddle is working fine in Firefox.

Comment: It's not working in my Firefox. Are you sure Firefox isn't caching them?

Comment: I'm sure, I just put the site up an hour ago. Interesting...it's working in my Firefox but not yours. It's also working for me in IE.