# Django - loading large images includes extra styling

Tags: python, django, image, django-imagekit, python-imaging-library

When loading large images (600x300px) in Django, extra styling is added preventing the image from being displayed.

page.html

```
<img src="{{article.image.url}}">
```

The output, when inspected through Google Chrome:

```
<img src="/media/img/600x160_1.png" style="display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important; opacity: 0 !important; background-position: 0px 0px;" width="0" height="0">
```

I cannot find any reason for this occurring and when I replace the image with a smaller sized one (300x150px) it loads fine without the extra styling content.

I am using bootstrap, but removing all the css and javascript files still results in the same error. I am using imagekit to upload the images and have Pillow installed in my local env too.

Comment: Where is the logic that adds the extra styling?

Comment: There is no logic that adds extra styling, it is just appearing out of nowhere. Chrome inspector includes it in the "element.styling" section, I cannot find any trace of the origin at all.

Comment: Add some more context surrounding the `img` tag please. Are you sure there's absolute no javascript nor css when the page loads?

Comment: I have added the img tag? The top code section is in the html file, the second is the output when rendered.

Comment: Yes I can see that, what I mean is to add more code surrounding the img tag, the elements enclosing it.

Comment: It sounds like Django is not the culprit here, but a JS library or CSS file. To verify this, use the "view source" option in Chrome to inspect the source code as sent by Django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the issue causing this:

Duplicate uploaded images on my test server ( I was using the same image ) was causing an error.

The output img src was:

```
<img src="/media/img/600X160_1.png">
```

When I removed the "_1" from this, it solved the problem:

```
<img src="/media/img/600X160.png">
```

By preventing duplicate file names (I added the upload time to the end of the image) I solved this peculiar issue.

Comment: It's likely that this was not the issue but rather an adblocker preventing you from seeing the image. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13980272/images-not-appearing-on-site-accessible-directly-through-url